# Memory Allocation Error using pkgmk on Solaris10?

Tags: unix, package, solaris

I am currently trying to use pkgmk on a Solaris10-x86 machine. When I run the command

```
pkgmk -o -b $(HOME)/solbuild/pkg_solaris
```

it returns this error:

```
## Building pkgmap from package prototype file.
pkgmk: ERROR: memory allocation failure
## Packaging was not successful.
```

My first thought was that this is an out of free memory error, however I am not sure that it could be. I have close to a gigabyte free in the / partition and 12 gigabytes free in the $(HOME) partition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be confusing lack of memory and lack of disk space, not to mention you are asking in the wrong site.

Comment: After trying a lot of different methods to fix this, I am not quite sure what the exact issue was. What I had to do was create a completely new vm on a different machine. I have not had any issues since, but the new vm actually has less memory than the old vm. The only difference between the vm's besides the memory was that on the first one that failed I was running out of hard disk space. That is why I thought it was the hard disk rather than the memory as the error indicated. @jlliagre My mistake. I am sorry if I caused offense, as you can see I am new around here :).

Comment: No problem. Was the out of disk space issue affecting /tmp ?

Comment: Yes. The hard drive was partitioned in the default way for Solaris in that `/export/home/` had space but `/` and everything else besides `/export/home/` had very little.

Comment: If you used Solaris default partitioning, /tmp was not consuming space in the root file system but using tmpfs which consumes virtual memory (swap+RAM). Having too large file(s) in it might then have explained an out of memory condition.

Comment: I saw this error when my prototype file syntax was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error when /var was full.

Deleting some file from /var resolved this problem.